# last update in mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

Is there any way to find last update Document in Collection? in other way sort collection by update

somethings like this

```
people = Person.objects.order_by_update()
```

or i must add update time for each doc?

I use `mongodb`, `mongoengine`, `flask`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add a field such as `last_updated_time` if you want to be able to sort in this way.  Also, since you're sorting on it, you should probably index it.

The only thing that mongodb stores by default is `_id`, which can be used roughly as a `created_time` timestamp.